# Why couchbase lite is always syncronizing

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am using couchbase lite 1.4 on Android. I have noted that my `Database` object is always synchronizing data, even when there is not changes in my server database.
This is my code :

```
master.addChangeListener(new Database.ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(Database.ChangeEvent event) {

                    if (event.isExternal()) {
                        for (DocumentChange dc : event.getChanges()) {
                            if (dc.isDeletion()) {
                                Document doc = event.getSource().getDocument(dc.getDocumentId());
                                try {
                                    doc.purge();
                                } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                                    Log.i("Synchronization","error"+e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                            Log.i("Synchronization",
                                    "total documents"+master.getDocumentCount());
                            Log.i("Synchronization",
                                    "id=>"+dc.getDocumentId()+ " revision=>"+ 
                                            dc.getRevisionId()+ " is deletion ?"+dc.isDeletion() +
                                            "is conflict ?"+dc.isConflict());
                            Log.i("Synchronization",
                                    "total documents are"+master.getDocumentCount());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            ViewHolder.initAllViews(master, work);
```

and this is what I see on my logcat:

```
05-31 19:30:57.544 I/Synchronization: id=>71ad7c09474bb379973a586d41faa376 revision=>3-ff6f2413c947e6679bba9c5d9a8ed056 es borrado?true esta en conflicto?false
05-31 19:31:07.759 I/Synchronization: total documentos 1165510
05-31 19:31:17.951 I/Synchronization: total documentos 1165510
05-31 19:31:17.951 I/Synchronization: id=>c034b94e3b0d2331b90e5ec801bcb83f revision=>11-174ab092fae645e611832a1532d53d7c es borrado?true esta en conflicto?false
05-31 19:31:28.107 I/Synchronization: total documentos1165510
05-31 19:31:38.268 I/Synchronization: total documentos1165510
05-31 19:31:38.269 I/Synchronization: id=>d0bbb7231659b48fa893e34cc4c2b90e revision=>12-a990bdc7881d8cc45fd1585afbeb91e2 es borrado?true esta en conflicto?false
05-31 19:31:48.437 I/Synchronization: total documentos1165510
05-31 19:31:58.710 I/Synchronization: total documentos1165510
05-31 19:31:58.710 I/Synchronization: id=>dbebc1b9c32f33a90a124560cf8b0a3a revision=>11-295d06f0148c4cbbe96920a517786ada es borrado?true esta en conflicto?false
05-31 19:32:08.902 I/Synchronization: total documentos 1165510
05-31 19:32:19.135 I/Synchronization: total documentos 1165510
05-31 19:32:19.135 I/Synchronization: id=>434c1966903c13895699240e1198d8e8 revision=>9-0ca58c84c7ddf09edd1e15f22c3bdafb es borrado?true esta en conflicto?false
05-31 19:32:29.315 I/Synchronization: total documentos 1165510:
```

as you can see I am always getting the same number of total documents

> 1165510

so the document are never purged but the database is always syncronizing data , that is my problem.
In the other hand on the Database server site if I try to find a document by the Id (one I copy from the log cat for example the last one : 434c1966903c13895699240e1198d8e8 )  I get this answer by the server :

[image]

Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

New added: I am facing that the problem comes when I delete documents in the server site doing

> "_deleted":true

Comment: There is no such version of Couchbase Lite.  Please double check that.

Comment: Indeed , sorry fixed

Comment: `Deleting` a document won't stop a document from replicating to other databases. And if you use `Purge` instead, then you will be able to remove completely and won't be replicated to other databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things here:

- Purging a deleted document will not change the document count.  Those
  documents *are* being purged.
- Also, a document that is purged locally will be restored, locally, by
  a replication that targets the local db (pull from or push to).

To quote @Jay, who posted a correct answer in a comment:

`Deleting a document (at the server) won't stop a document from replicating to other databases.`

Using Purge (at the server), instead, will remove the document completely, preventing its replication to other databases.  (Note, of course, that it will not cause the document to be *deleted* in the other databases.)